# How would I solve for a?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

[image]

"Solve for a such that the above function is continuous from -infinity to +infinity"

I am struggling with this problem because a is only present in one of the parts of the function and if I set the above part of the function to -4, it is undefined.

Any help?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to -4^-}f(x)$?

Comment: Ah yes! Now it has clicked! Thanks!

Comment: Can I suggest that you ask one example question of the type and then try to apply what you learn from that before asking another similar one. You need to think about what causes problems in these cases and how you make continuous pieces fit together at the boundary between them.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I think it is worth telling you that there were about 5-6 questions total on finding the unknown so that the piecewise function is continuous in the problem set I was doing. My first question helped me answer all other questions except the one above. The reason this question confused me was because the unknown variable was only in one part of the function. My intention was not to spam if that's what it came off as.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $$2x^3+9x^2+11x+28=(x+4)(2x^2+x+7)$$